# How do I create a "new row" delimiter when trying to convert a long chain to a CSV in R?

Tags: r, csv, row, delimiter

Picture a 1x1 matrix, named xyz.

If you outputted this matrix xyz it would read:

> [1] "New York City,1960,1988,Los Angeles,1962,1975,Chicago,1975,2005"

I want to convert this to a CSV file with 3 columns "City" "Start Year" and "End Year" and three rows, one for each city. Is there a way I could  indicate where the next row should start?

I've heard vaguely about delimiters like "0x0A" and "\r" but I'm not entirely sure how they work and how they would work in the context of an R program.

Comment: Split the string by a comma and convert it to a `matrix` with `ncol = 3` and `byrow = TRUE`?

Answer (score 0):

If your data are already this structured, a simple `matrix(splitvalues, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)` should be enough to get the basic form you want.

Example:

```
xyz <- "New York City,1960,1988,Los Angeles,1962,1975,Chicago,1975,2005"
matrix(strsplit(xyz, ",", TRUE)[[1]], ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1]            [,2]   [,3]  
# [1,] "New York City" "1960" "1988"
# [2,] "Los Angeles"   "1962" "1975"
# [3,] "Chicago"       "1975" "2005"
```

---

If you prefer a `data.frame` (since you have different data types in different columns) you can do something like the following:

```
xyzM <- matrix(strsplit(xyz, ",", TRUE)[[1]], ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
xyzDF <- data.frame(xyzM, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
xyzDF[] <- lapply(xyzDF, type.convert)
xyzDF
#              X1   X2   X3
# 1 New York City 1960 1988
# 2   Los Angeles 1962 1975
# 3       Chicago 1975 2005
str(xyzDF)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ X1: Factor w/ 3 levels "Chicago","Los Angeles",..: 3 2 1
# $ X2: int  1960 1962 1975
# $ X3: int  1988 1975 2005
```

---

If things were not balanced, and you don't feel like futzing with regex (I rarely do), you can cheat a little bit with `gsub` and `strsplit`. I've also included `stri_split` from the "stringi" package because it conveniently converts split output into a `matrix`:

```
xyz <- "New York City,1960,1988,Los Angeles,1962,1975,1995,Chicago,1975,2005"
library(stringi)
stri_split_fixed(
  strsplit(
    gsub(",([A-Z])", "crazyRowDelimiter\\1", xyz), ## Make a row delimiter
    "crazyRowDelimiter", TRUE)[[1]],               ## Split on that delimiter
  ",", simplify = TRUE)                            ## Split again on commas
#      [,1]            [,2]   [,3]   [,4]  
# [1,] "New York City" "1960" "1988" ""    
# [2,] "Los Angeles"   "1962" "1975" "1995"
# [3,] "Chicago"       "1975" "2005" ""
```

Alternatively, split the string first, then split the results into a `list` by identifying which values are letters, and finally convert the output to a `matrix`:

```
xyz <- "New York City,1960,1988,Los Angeles,1962,1975,1995,Chicago,1975,2005"
library(stringi)
xyzS <- strsplit(xyz, ",", TRUE)[[1]]
stri_list2matrix(split(xyzS, cumsum(grepl("[A-Za-z]", xyzS))), byrow = TRUE)
     [,1]            [,2]   [,3]   [,4]  
# [1,] "New York City" "1960" "1988" NA    
# [2,] "Los Angeles"   "1962" "1975" "1995"
# [3,] "Chicago"       "1975" "2005" NA
```

Comment: Thank you! Now what if the data were structured like this:

"New York City,1960,1988,Los Angeles,1962,1975,1995,Chicago,1975,2005"

Where row 1 would have 3 columns of data, row 2 would have 4 columns, and row 3 would have 3 columns. Is there any easy way to handle that? Or should I go to the trouble of adding a delimiter in rows 1 and 2 so it reads:

"New York City,1960,1988,,Los Angeles,1962,1975,1995,Chicago,1975,2005,"

and then do your method? matrix(strsplit(xyz, ",", TRUE)[[1]], ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)

Comment: @DocStev, see the update at the bottom of my answer.